# renaming an admin menu item with decimal array index number

Tags: php, menus, admin, admin-menu

I am trying to rename a menu item on my administration dashboard.
Using the $GLOBALS['menu'], I have found the following array indexes

> [26.0648] => Array  (    [0] => M.E. Calendar ...

and

> [26] => Array       (    [0] => Products ...

After using the following code:

```
global $menu;
global $submenu;
$menu[26.0648][0] = 'Event Calendar';
```

The result is that the "M.E. Calendar" item has not changed, whereas the Products item has changed to

> [26] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => Event Calendar
>               [1] => edit_products
>               [2] => edit.php?post_type=product

Is there a way I can rename the menu item with the decimal array index number? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a string as key:

```
$menu['26.0648'][0] = 'Event Calendar';
```

If you write the key as a number, it will truncate the decimal to an integer, so 26.0648 will be truncated to 26.